# Can't start H2O in R: Error in h2o.init() H2O failed to start, stopping execution

Tags: r, h2o

I'm trying to use H2O on a RHEL 6.7 server with R 3.5.0.
This is what happens when I issue the `h2o.init()` command after loading the package with `library(h2o)`:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /tmp/Rtmp0k66FQ/h2o_enrico_started_from_r.out
    /tmp/Rtmp0k66FQ/h2o_enrico_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Cannot load library from path lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_gpu.so
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Cannot load library from path lib/linux_64/libxgboost4j_omp.so
Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_omp.so
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
01-26 17:06:39.858 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Found XGBoost backend with library: xgboost4j_minimal
01-26 17:06:39.958 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Your system supports only minimal version of XGBoost (no GPUs, no multithreading)!
01-26 17:06:39.959 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
01-26 17:06:39.959 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-xu
01-26 17:06:39.959 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Build git hash: 3ad2470fdea521c2d6fb3aa31d8c766042bdb992
01-26 17:06:39.959 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-master-4525-7-g3ad2470
01-26 17:06:39.959 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Build project version: 3.22.1.1
01-26 17:06:39.960 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Build age: 29 days
01-26 17:06:39.960 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
01-26 17:06:39.960 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Built on: '2018-12-28 14:04:50'
01-26 17:06:39.969 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.969 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.973 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.973 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.973 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.973 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.973 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost Build git branch: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.973 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost Build git hash: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.974 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost Build git describe: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.974 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost Build project version: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.974 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost Built by: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.975 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost Built on: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.975 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git branch: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.976 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git hash: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.976 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git describe: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.976 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build project version: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.976 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built by: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.976 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built on: (unknown)
01-26 17:06:39.976 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_enrico_kcp980, -ip, localhost, -web_ip, localhost, -port, 54321, -ice_r
oot, /tmp/Rtmp0k66FQ]
01-26 17:06:39.977 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 32
01-26 17:06:39.977 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 1.92 GB
01-26 17:06:39.977 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 26.67 GB
01-26 17:06:39.977 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_20 (from Oracle Corporation)
01-26 17:06:39.981 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-ea]
01-26 17:06:39.981 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: OS version: Linux 2.6.32-554.el6.x86_64 (amd64)
01-26 17:06:39.981 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 757.37 GB
01-26 17:06:39.981 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1548518797511
01-26 17:06:39.982 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: User name: 'enrico'
01-26 17:06:39.982 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: IPv6 stack selected: false
01-26 17:06:39.982 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: ib0 (ib0), fe80:0:0:0:e61d:2d03:e1:4371%ib0
01-26 17:06:39.982 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: ib0 (ib0), 10.168.22.9
01-26 17:06:39.983 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth4 (eth4), fe80:0:0:0:a236:9fff:fe13:9594%eth4
01-26 17:06:39.983 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth4 (eth4), 10.168.16.15
01-26 17:06:39.984 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth0 (eth0), fe80:0:0:0:be30:5bff:fef6:9c14%eth0
01-26 17:06:39.984 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth0 (eth0), 10.168.8.9
01-26 17:06:39.984 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
01-26 17:06:39.984 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
01-26 17:06:39.984 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Selected H2O.CLOUD_MULTICAST_IF: name:lo (lo) doesn't support multicast
01-26 17:06:40.027 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: H2O node running in unencrypted mode.
01-26 17:06:40.038 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Internal communication uses port: 54322
01-26 17:06:40.038 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Listening for HTTP and REST traffic on http://127.0.0.1:54321/
01-26 17:06:40.040 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: H2O cloud name: 'H2O_started_from_R_enrico_kcp980' on localhost/127.0.0.1:54321, static configuration based on -flatfile null
01-26 17:06:40.041 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: If you have trouble connecting, try SSH tunneling from your local machine (e.g., via port 55555):
01-26 17:06:40.041 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO:   1. Open a terminal and run 'ssh -L 55555:localhost:54321 enrico@127.0.0.1'
01-26 17:06:40.041 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO:   2. Point your browser to http://localhost:55555
01-26 17:06:41.838 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Log dir: '/tmp/Rtmp0k66FQ/h2ologs'
01-26 17:06:41.838 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Cur dir: '/home/enrico'
01-26 17:06:41.869 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Subsystem for distributed import from HTTP/HTTPS successfully initialized
01-26 17:06:41.881 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: HDFS subsystem successfully initialized
01-26 17:06:41.887 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: S3 subsystem successfully initialized
01-26 17:06:41.946 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: GCS subsystem successfully initialized
01-26 17:06:41.947 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Flow dir: '/home/enrico/h2oflows'
01-26 17:06:42.026 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Cloud of size 1 formed [localhost/127.0.0.1:54321]
01-26 17:06:42.053 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Registered parsers: [GUESS, ARFF, XLS, SVMLight, AVRO, PARQUET, CSV]
01-26 17:06:42.123 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Watchdog extension initialized
01-26 17:06:42.123 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: XGBoost extension initialized
01-26 17:06:42.126 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: KrbStandalone extension initialized
01-26 17:06:42.126 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Registered 3 core extensions in: 1099ms
01-26 17:06:42.126 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Registered H2O core extensions: [Watchdog, XGBoost, KrbStandalone]
01-26 17:06:43.971 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Registered: 169 REST APIs in: 1844ms
01-26 17:06:43.987 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Registered REST API extensions: [XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4]
01-26 17:06:46.023 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Registered: 242 schemas in 2035ms
01-26 17:06:46.024 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: H2O started in 8483ms
01-26 17:06:46.024 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO:
01-26 17:06:46.024 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321
01-26 17:06:46.024 127.0.0.1:54321       83682  main      INFO:
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] FALSE
[1] 504
[1] ""
Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
```

The standard output logfile shows the same information up to the last `INFO` statement (i.e.: no errors) and the error log file is completely empty.

Any help in getting this to work would be much appreciated! I have used H2O in the past and I'm a big fan.

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't worked with h2o before, but it looks like it's probably a problem with the installation of xgboost. The [install page](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installing-r-package-with-gpu-support) includes a section on installing with GPU support specifically for R.  Since your error starts with `Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_gpu.so`, maybe that's the first thing to check?

Comment: @BrendanA., No the xgboost warnings are not related to the H2O error. H2O looks for the xgboost library to use GPU and multithreading processing and, if it doesn't find it it as here, it uses a minimal, fallback solution, see here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a proxy issue.
Unsetting the `http_proxy` environment variable allows R to properly connect to H2O, i.e.:

```
library(h2o)
Sys.unsetenv("http_proxy")
h2o.init()

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /tmp/RtmpqEIs7x/h2o_ferreen2_started_from_r.out
    /tmp/RtmpqEIs7x/h2o_ferreen2_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         2 seconds 257 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster timezone:       Europe/Zurich 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
    H2O cluster version:        3.22.1.1 
    H2O cluster version age:    1 month  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_enrico_azr433 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   26.67 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    32 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  32 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually H2O *did* start here.  The message saying to open Flow in your web browser is the sign.

But the R client couldn’t reach H2O and decided to give up.

The message at the bottom has a 504.

That’s HTTP status 504.  Which is probably a RHEL firewall blocking port 54321.  You need to open port 54321 in the firewall.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thank you. I didn't realise that 504 was an HTTP error code. I will ask the server admin to open the port and see if that fixes it. Will report back.

Comment: It turns out iptables is not running and port 54321 is not blocked. I can start H2O using java -jar h2o.jar with no errors but I still get a gateway timeout error (i.e.: 504) and neither R nor the browser will connect to it. Any other idea?

Comment: Try to disable SELinux.  Check whether there are proxy settings, and if there are, turn them off for localhost.  This is 100% something to do with the configuration of your environment.

Comment: Indeed, it was a proxy issue, though it might even be a bug in H2O. Posted resolution in another answer.